Define a function by integrating a solution of NDSolve
usol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x], u[0, x] == 0, 
u[t, 0] == Sin[t], u[t, 5] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 5}];
int[x_] := Integrate[D[usol[t, x], x], {t, 0, 10}];
int[1]

D::ivar: 1 is not a valid variable.
How to define such a function correctly?

Use Derivative and specify the 1st derivative of the 2nd argument: int[x_] := NIntegrate[Derivative[0, 1][usol][t, x], {t, 0, 10}]

Or using = instead of :=

Look at:
int[x_] := Integrate[D[usol[t, x], x], {t, 0, 10}];

If you now write int[1] this gets transformed, before the differentiation is evaluated, into
Integrate[D[usol[t, 1], 1], {t, 0, 10}]

as you can convince yourself by "Trace".
On the other hand, if x has no value and you write
int[x_] = Integrate[D[usol[t, x], x], {t, 0, 10}]

this is differentiated at once with symbolic x.
